# Where Is JanusGraph's Gremlin-Console Finding its Tinkerpop-Server's "conf/remote.yaml"?

Tags: websocket, docker-container, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

## Problem

Where is [JanusGraph [Docker-container]](https://hub.docker.com/r/janusgraph/janusgraph) [Gremlin-Console](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/) getting its [`conf/remote.yaml`](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-console/conf/remote.yaml) from?

```json
[o.a.t.g.d.ConnectionPool.gremlin-driver-host-scheduler-1] ::    Opening connection pool on Host{address=localhost/127.0.0.1:8182, hostUri=ws://localhost:8182/gremlin}
[o.a.t.g.d.Connection.gremlin-driver-conn-scheduler-1] ::    Created new connection for ws://localhost:8182/gremlin
```

## Reproduction

### Steps

1. Create-and-Startup [JanusGraph [Docker-container]](https://hub.docker.com/r/janusgraph/janusgraph)
   `docker run -d -p 8182:8182 janusgraph/janusgraph`
2. Results

   1. Expected (1-or-multiple of)

      1. [Gremlin Folder [For Gremlin-Console and/or Gremlin-Server]](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/)
      2. [Gremlin Configuration File(s) [`remote.yaml` in `conf/` or anywhere]](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/tree/master/gremlin-console/conf)
      3. [`remote.yaml` Configuration-File](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-console/conf/remote.yaml) directory to be printed-out in logs
   2. Actually

      1. [No Gremlin Folder Found](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin)
      2. No Gremlin Configuration File(s) Found
      3. `conf/remote.yaml` Not Found. [`whereis` (Linux Command)](https://linuxize.com/post/whereis-command-in-linux/) did not return any locations
   3. Questions

      1. Is `localhost:8182/gremlin` the default for Gremlin-Server?

         1. Or is it a default Gremlin GraphDB name for Gremlin or JanusGraph?
      2. Where is this [`remote.yaml`](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-console/conf/remote.yaml) coming from?

         1. Why is there a separate [`gremlin-server.yaml`](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-dist/src/assembly/static/conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml)? Is it the same thing?
      3. Where is the more detailed document(s) on [JanusGraph's `tinkerpop.server`](https://docs.janusgraph.org/getting-started/installation/#running-janusgraph-inside-a-docker-container)?

Comment: Thanks for showing me where the `remote.yaml` is located [@HadoopMarc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16598470/hadoopmarc)! <br />
Future readers: `/opt/janusgraph/conf/remote.yaml` at the time of this recording.

Comment: Removed images as suggested by [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/162698/rob) in the [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76203371/janusgraph-propertykey-is-not-a-user-defined-key) <br />
Hope this helps [improve reader experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) as Graph-Databases get more popular and the community develops!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a concept "gremlin folder". JanusGraph includes TinkerPop/gremlin and the JanusGraph folder is the gremlin folder.

```
docker exec -it aceffdee582e ls conf
hadoop-graph                    jvm-8.options
janusgraph-berkeleyje-es-server.properties  log4j-console.properties
janusgraph-berkeleyje-lucene-server.properties  log4j-server.properties
janusgraph-berkeleyje-server.properties     logback.xml
janusgraph-cql-es-server.properties     remote-graph-binary.yaml
janusgraph-cql-server.properties        remote-graph.properties
janusgraph-inmemory-server.properties       remote-objects.yaml
janusgraph-server.yaml              remote.yaml
jvm-11.options                  solr
```