# JanusGraph-PropertyKey Is Not A User-Defined-Key

Tags: cassandra-3.0, docker-container, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, java-17

## Problem

Why is JanusGraph throwing-up a User-Defined-Key problem when I'm just trying to make an index?

### Logs

```json
2023-05-08 12:40:25,640 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:9042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2023-05-08 12:40:25,731 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.DefaultMavenCoordinates.main] ::     DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.15.0
2023-05-08 12:40:26,173 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.t.Clock.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::   Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-05-08 12:40:26,414 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::     [JanusGraph Session|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=6415177b)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
2023-05-08 12:40:26,643 [INFO] [o.j.g.i.UniqueInstanceIdRetriever.main] ::   Generated unique-instance-id=c0a8563c15928-rmt-lap-win201
2023-05-08 12:40:26,657 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:9042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2023-05-08 12:40:26,684 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.t.Clock.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::   Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-05-08 12:40:26,724 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::     [JanusGraph Session|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=114c356b)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
2023-05-08 12:40:26,739 [INFO] [o.j.d.c.ExecutorServiceBuilder.main] ::  Initiated fixed thread pool of size 40
2023-05-08 12:40:26,845 [INFO] [o.j.g.d.StandardJanusGraph.main] ::  Gremlin script evaluation is disabled
2023-05-08 12:40:26,872 [INFO] [o.j.d.l.k.KCVSLog.main] ::   Loaded unidentified ReadMarker start time 2023-05-08T17:40:26.872018Z into org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller@8d8f754
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key must be a user defined key: null
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:220)
    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem$IndexBuilder.addKey(ManagementSystem.java:789)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)

Process finished with exit code 130
```

## Reproduction

### Steps

1. Create-and-Startup [Cassandra [Docker container]](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra)
2. Create-and-Startup [JanusGraph [Docker container]](https://hub.docker.com/r/janusgraph/janusgraph) (Optional)
3. Create a Java-Project with Maven this `POM.XML`
4. Create-and-Add `log4j2.xml`, `remote-graph.properties`, and `remote-objects.yaml` (Optional)
5. Create-and-Run [Main.java](https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/index-management/index-performance/) for Indexing using [`JanusGraphManagement`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-core/0.1.1/org/janusgraph/core/schema/JanusGraphManagement.html)

   1. `PropertyKey()` seems right because its in the [latest index document](https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/)
   2. `MapReduceIndexManagement()` seems wrong because its [not in the latest document](https://docs.janusgraph.org/v0.2/advanced-topics/index-admin/)
   3. `JanusGraphManagement` [their example doesn't show a example](https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/index-management/index-performance/) of how they classed [their own interface](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.janusgraph/janusgraph-core/0.1.1/org/janusgraph/core/schema/JanusGraphManagement.html)
6. Results

   1. Expected: Program to run
   2. Actually: Runtime Error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key must be a user defined key: null`

      1. Removing all the optional steps still produce the same error

### Code

```
│   pom.xml
│
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │       Main.java
│   │   │
│   │   └───resources
│   │       │   log4j2.xml
```

#### `pom.xml`

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-cql</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

#### `Main.java`

```java
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraph;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory;
import org.janusgraph.core.PropertyKey;
import org.janusgraph.core.schema.JanusGraphManagement;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql").set("storage.hostname", "localhost:9042").open();
        JanusGraphManagement janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
        PropertyKey propertyKey = janusGraphManagement.getPropertyKey("_id");
        janusGraphManagement.buildIndex("_id", Vertex.class).addKey(propertyKey).buildCompositeIndex();
        janusGraphManagement.commit();
        janusGraph.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fix.

```java
PropertyKey propertyKey = janusGraphManagement.getOrCreatePropertyKey("_id");
```

```bash
2023-05-09 08:46:38,617 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:9042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2023-05-09 08:46:38,689 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.DefaultMavenCoordinates.main] ::     DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.15.0
2023-05-09 08:46:39,124 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.t.Clock.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::   Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-05-09 08:46:39,385 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::     [JanusGraph Session|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=7b9f753a)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
2023-05-09 08:46:39,610 [INFO] [o.j.g.i.UniqueInstanceIdRetriever.main] ::   Generated unique-instance-id=c0a8563c11168-rmt-lap-win201
2023-05-09 08:46:39,625 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:9042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2023-05-09 08:46:39,651 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.t.Clock.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::   Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-05-09 08:46:39,693 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::     [JanusGraph Session|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=1ce6602a)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
2023-05-09 08:46:39,707 [INFO] [o.j.d.c.ExecutorServiceBuilder.main] ::  Initiated fixed thread pool of size 40
2023-05-09 08:46:39,818 [INFO] [o.j.g.d.StandardJanusGraph.main] ::  Gremlin script evaluation is disabled
2023-05-09 08:46:39,844 [INFO] [o.j.d.l.k.KCVSLog.main] ::   Loaded unidentified ReadMarker start time 2023-05-09T13:46:39.844155Z into org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller@ff23ae7

Process finished with exit code 0
```

There might not be any `JanusGraphManagement` method like `set()`, `create()`, `insert()`, `make()`, or `add()` for new `PropertyKeys`. But, they've conjoined get-and-create together like making a `SQL` `SELECT`-or-`CREATE`/`INSERT` or a `Java` `Getter`-and-`Setter` as one method.

Finding-and-realizing this just threw me through a loop.

```java
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraph;
import org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory;
import org.janusgraph.core.PropertyKey;
import org.janusgraph.core.schema.JanusGraphManagement;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql").set("storage.hostname", "localhost:9042").open();
        JanusGraphManagement janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
        PropertyKey propertyKey = janusGraphManagement.getOrCreatePropertyKey("_id");
        janusGraphManagement.buildIndex("_id", Vertex.class).addKey(propertyKey).buildCompositeIndex();
        janusGraphManagement.commit();
        janusGraph.close();
    }
}
```